# How can I order a SQL query that uses UNION so that it returns the data in the order that the queries are in?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL Query along the following lines:

```
SELECT R.NUMERIC_VAL, 'A'  /* query A */
  FROM TABLE_1  
 WHERE TABLE_1.DATE = TO_DATE('04/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
 UNION
SELECT E.NUMBER_VALUE, 'B' /* query B */
  FROM TABLE_2 
 WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
 UNION
SELECT E.OTHER_NUMBER_VALUE, 'C' /* query C */
  FROM TABLE_2
 WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
 ORDER BY 2
```

As you can see, my current solution fetches back the letters A, B and C and orders the query by the second column. I know for a fact that this query will always bring back 1 row per query. I was wondering if there was any way of getting the query to bring back the data in the order that the queries are currently written in, without having to use the second column? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `order by` to get the results in the order that you want.  SQL tables and SQL results are inherently unordered when there is no `order by`, except for a few database-specific exceptions (for instance, MySQL guarantees the ordering when using `group by`).

`UNION` and `UNION ALL` do not guarantee the ordering of the results.  In fact, in many databases, `UNION` will return the results in alphabetical order (by the first column) as part of the duplicate removal process.

You can replace the `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.  Although this is not guaranteed to return the results in a particular order, it will typically return them in the order written:

```
SELECT R.NUMERIC_VAL, 'A'  /* query A */
FROM TABLE_1  
WHERE TABLE_1.DATE = TO_DATE('04/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
UNION ALL
SELECT E.NUMBER_VALUE, 'B' /* query B */
FROM TABLE_2 
WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
UNION ALL
SELECT E.OTHER_NUMBER_VALUE, 'C' /* query C */
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

However, I would advise you to keep the `ORDER BY`.

If you don't want the second column, use a subquery:

```
select NUMERIC_VAL
from (SELECT R.NUMERIC_VAL, 'A' as ordering /* query A */
      FROM TABLE_1  
      WHERE TABLE_1.DATE = TO_DATE('04/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT E.NUMBER_VALUE, 'B' /* query B */
      FROM TABLE_2 
      WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT E.OTHER_NUMBER_VALUE, 'C' /* query C */
      FROM TABLE_2
      WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
     ) t
ORDER BY ordering;
```

Comment: Just realized that we both made the same mistake and didn't alias the first column to the same name. I fixed it now in my answer and would suggest you do the same :)

Comment: @inflagranti . . . Different names for the first column in `union` doesn't make a difference.  The first alias encountered is the one used for naming the output column.

Comment: @GordonLindoff: Are you sure this holds for any database? Because I'm pretty sure I had issues with this before.

Comment: Ok, it looks like there might have been some bugs in some older version of DB2 which didn't allow mixed names. Definitely it does now.

Comment: Incorrect. UNION on its own only guarantees uniqueness, not ordering. Oracle is free to optimise the query to move the subqueries around if it wants to, and return the results any way it wants. You only get guaranteed order if you add an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: I think his point was that in 99% of the cases as a side effect of its implementation the result of a UNION will be ordered by column A, B, C, etc. since ordering is normally used to eliminate duplicates. And the same goes for UNION ALL: in 99% of the cases the DB will not do some extra work and leave the order the way it appears in the query.

Comment: @inflagranti, my comment was regarding the previous version of this answer. It was since edited and is now correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT NumVal FROM
(
    SELECT R.NUMERIC_VAL AS NumVal, 1 AS queryNo
    FROM TABLE_1  
    WHERE TABLE_1.DATE = TO_DATE('04/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
    UNION
    SELECT E.NUMBER_VALUE AS NumVal, 2 AS queryNo
    FROM TABLE_2 
    WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    UNION
    SELECT E.OTHER_NUMBER_VALUE AS NumVal, 3 AS queryNo
    FROM TABLE_2
    WHERE TABLE_2.DATE = TO_DATE('05/04/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
) T
ORDER BY queryNo ASC
```

Though I don't see a way to do this reliably without the fake 2nd column, but this way at least it's not part of the result. Also you might just try using `UNION ALL`, which means that it does not have to eliminate duplicate values, *likely* preserving order, but as I said, probably not reliably.

Comment: This would still return the second column in the query though would it not?